# Can favicon just accept png or jpg file type please?

Tags: html, favicon

I'm getting an error in Firefox console of favicon not included in page.

Can favicon just accept png or jpg file type by the browser?

**UPDATE:**
I've added the link to the favicon as suggested:
[image]

I still get the error but it is a new error:

[image]

Comment: What kind of backend are you using? May be something to do with your routing?

Comment: @Cjmarkham it could be. i'm using node js and express

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to know is to test it. Just put a PNG image path in your HTML (using `link`) or the manifest.json to specify various icons for different device audiences (the app doesn't need to be a complete PWA). Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/icons to learn about the specification. For the example of the `link` element in the HTML, I used the following code inside the `<head/>` element, and I was able to see the Google icon (which is a PNG on the tab):

```
<head>
  <title>Using PNG Icon</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<link-to-image.png>">
</head>
```

This should update the icon for you. Note that sometimes a browser might cache the resources, so consider a hard refresh to load the fresh copy of the web document.

Also, it is interesting to note that [caniuse website](https://caniuse.com/?search=favicon) specifies that a PNG file is preferable.

Comment: It looks like that should work but when I tried it it said it could not load favicon.png. I'll update my post. If my code is correct and it doesn't work I might guess that method may only work in PWAs.